# Custom validation with different root controls in reactive forms

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

I have `heroForm` which contains form array `entities`. Every item is `FormGroup`.

Here is example:

```
this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
      entities: this.fb.array([]),
    });
```

Here is how I am adding new group to array:

```
  addEntity() {
    this.entities.push(this.createFormGroup(new Address()));
  }
```

Here is how I am creating single group:

```
  createFormGroup(address: Address) {
    return this.fb.group({
      'street': new FormControl(address.street, []),
      'city': new FormControl(address.city, [duplicateCity]),
      'state': new FormControl(address.state, []),
      'zip': new FormControl(address.zip, [])
    });
  }
```

Here is custom validation function:

```
function duplicateCity(input: FormControl): any {
  if (!input.root || !(<FormGroup>input.root).controls) {
    return null;
  }

  // Do some validation.
  input.value === ...
}
```

Now I want to iterate over `City` trough controls and compare their values. If I found that name of city occurred twice I would like to return error.

Problem is I don't want to compare same control, I want to skip it. What should be accurate way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I missed this part:

```
function duplicateCity(id: number): any {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
    if (!control.root || !(<FormGroup>control.root).controls) {
      return null;
    }

    // Do some logic

  };
```

Function `duplicateCity(id: number)` is now factory which returns validation function. I can pass `ID` as parameter dynamically during creation of form group like in following example:

```
createFormGroup(address: Address, id: number) {
    return this.fb.group({
      'street': new FormControl(address.street, []),
      'city': new FormControl(address.city, [duplicateCity(id)]),
      'state': new FormControl(address.state, []),
      'zip': new FormControl(address.zip, [])
    });
```